# Implement generic abstract jaxrs service

Tags: java, web-services, generics, jax-rs

I'm struggling on implementing a generic abstract jaxrs service without duplicating several jaxrs annotations.

So, for example, here is my service and entity structure:

**AbstractEntity.java**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public abstract class AbstractEntity {
    @XmlElement
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**AbstractService.java**

```java
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class AbstractService<T extends AbstractEntity> {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/details")
    public Response getEntityDetails(final T entity) {
        // just return the name of this entity
        return Response.ok(entity.getName()).build();
    }
}
```

The implementation is like:

**Car.java**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Car extends AbstractEntity {
    @XmlElement
    private String brand;

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }
}
```

**CarService.java**

```java
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/cars")
public class CarService extends AbstractService<Car> {
    // should provide the super getEntityDetails method with a Car entity
}
```

Now i want to POST my car entity to `/cars/details` to get the details (return the name "A5" which is implemented in the abstract service):

```xml
POST /cars/details
<car>
   <brand>Audi</brand>
   <name>A5</name>
</car>
```

Unfortunately, when I post it to my service, it says:

```
JAXRSUtils    W   .No message body reader found for request class : AbstractEntity, ContentType : application/xml.
WebApplicatio W   WebApplicationException has been caught : no cause is available
```

I can correct it, if I implement my `CarService` as follows:

**CarService.java**

```java
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/cars")
public class CarService extends AbstractService<Car> {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/details")
    @Override
    public Response getEntityDetails(final Car entity) {
        return super.getEntityDetails(entity);
    }
}
```

And removing all jaxrs annotations from the abstract service:

**AbstractService.java**

```java
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class AbstractService<T extends AbstractEntity> {
    public Response getEntityDetails(final T entity) {
        // just return the name of this entity
        return Response.ok(entity.getName()).build();
    }
}
```

The point is, that I have about 60 of these `CarService` implementations and I don't want to repeat the `getDetails` method with all it's jaxrs annotation in each service, because it's always the same (the same boilerplate).

Any ideas or solutions on that?

Answer (score 0):

potentially you may want to also have a look at more resource-oriented rest libraries to complement your JAX-RS codebase. They can do exactly that (path mappings, sorting, filtering, paging, etc.) without an annotation or abstract base class hell. crnk.io + jsonapi, graphql, falcor are such libraries. (disclaimer: I contribute to the first one)